# Why Sass or Scss converts color #ffe to #ffffee and add a ";" which could make the css file load slower?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Sass or Scss (.sass) is common in Ruby on Rails projects, but I just found that it converts the color such as:

```
background: #ffe
```

into

```
background: #ffffee;
```

why the extra bytes?  Also, why the extra `;` at the end?  Sass should automatically compile into a `.css` file, so the "extra semi-colon" at the end can be a good form if the users are editing the CSS file directly, but Sass is about automatic compiling, so why add a `;` to increase page load time?

Second, why the universal accepted `#ffe` expanded as `#ffffee`?  There isn't a modern browser that doesn't understand it...  (maybe except the browser on a low-end cell phone, but those pages are very unreadable anyways.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Output Sass using the compressed output mode and it will drop the last semicolon and use the more compact version of the color.

E.g.

```
echo "div { color: #ffe; }" | sass -t compressed --scss
```

Returns

```
div{color:#ffe}
```

Comment: can you incorporate that into Rails?  (probably in the haml gem)

Comment: I found that your line won't compress `#ffffee` into `#ffe` but this line will: `echo -e "div\n  color: #ffffee" | sass -t compressed` (but is in sass originally)

Comment: by the way, I found that Sass's `compressed` mode is the only one that converts `#ffffee` into `#ffe`, but it goes all the way: there is no white space even for line breaks...  so there is not a mode that can compress into `#ffe` while keeping nice line breaks.

Answer (score 4):

Two-fold reasoning. Readability + Consistency. The size difference is negligible, and if you are worried about speed time is better spent optimizing the code / removing repetitive properties rather than worrying about the semicolon. This allows for consistent writing

Comment: as I said, it is automatically generated.  Is `#ffe` less readable than `#ffffee`?  Is the last semi-colon at the end really so "readable"?  I really don't think so.  I think it adds up clutter.  Think of the list `[1, 3, 5]` Is it more readable or is `[1, 3, 5,]` more readable?

Comment: It is not about the readability of this particular fragment but the stylesheet as a whole. For example if you have more than one property, you will put semicolons for all lines but the last one -- aka inconsistency. Btw [1,3,5,] the comma goes against the coding standards, meanwhile the semicolon is de-facto in css.

Comment: so Sass is adding a `;` even for 1 property, and it looks ugly, and you can say, "it is for consistency."  Why does it need consistency really?  Consistent so that what?  Are people going to directly edit the generated css file?  No.  does it look better?  No.  I think the consistency is making look more ugly and making it load slower, so consistency really isn't so much preferred in this case.

Comment: That is one approach one might take. I don't use it so it doesn't matter. On the other hand some of us just prefer to have consistent readable code, whether it is generated or not. From the technical standpoint, YASS or SASS both do it because first they parse the stylesheet, and then generate the rules from scratch. Therefore the unified convention. They are not just copying and pasting your rules. As for the speed difference, like I mentioned the 8 bytes you are saving probably don't affect much.

Comment: if I ever need to examine the generated css, probably I prefer to look at `#ffe`, which is clear and simple, instead of interpreting `#ffffee` which takes me an extra split second to look at than `#ffe`